# Facebook share API/HTML URL

Tags: html, facebook

So i'm using the Facebook API for sharing pages but i'm encountering an issue with the URL aspect.
Basically the pages and content are built on the fly so I can't put a direct URL in. So I was wondering whether I could grab the URL of each specific page and put it in the facebook 'href' requirement.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button"></div>
```

So the 'date-href' needs to change depending upon the page it sits on, is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Just use any programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested:

```
$('.fb-share-button').click(function () {
            $(this).attr("data-href") = window.location.href;
        });
```

If you are working on a LocalHost, the script won't work, which is where I went wrong